# Image upload on checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, file-upload

I'm at a complete loss for this one at the moment.  Does anybody have any information as to how I can add a file upload field to checkout, and access this in an observer tied to sales_order_save_before?

I've gotten a file upload field to appear on checkout right now with a layout processor, but I am not sure how to actually pass the temp file location to my observer

Comment: Can you explain more details? Where you want to put the image upload?

Comment: I'd like to add it to the checkout form.  Forgive me, been working a little too hard lately and forgot to mention the most important part. I got as far as creating a little html template for a file upload and adding it with a layout processor. I can't seem to wrap my head around passing the temporary file location to the observer though

Comment: I'm thinking if I add in some javascript, and post to a controller manually via ajax, it should work

Comment: Has anybody do not get requirement to add File upload on checkout form ?? @JohnSweriduk, Do you got any answer to your Query , please add it here if yes